# Progress event for large Firebase queries?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, firebase

I have the following query:

```
fire = new Firebase 'ME.firebaseio.com'
users = fire.child 'venues/ID/users'
users.once 'value', (snapshot) ->
   # do things with snapshot.val()
   ...
```

I am loading 10+ mb of data, and the request takes around 1sec/mb. Is it possible to give the user a progress indicator as content streams in? Ideally I'd like to process the data as it comes in as well (not just notify).

I tried using the `on "child_added"` event instead, but it doesn't work as expected - instead of children streaming in at a consistent rate, they all come at once after the entire dataset is loaded (which takes 10-15 sec), so in practice it seems to be a less performant version of `on "value"`.

Comment: It is true that child_added downloads the initial data set before firing events. There are a few ways we could accomplish your goals here, but I'm having a very hard time understanding a use case where it's practical to download 10MB of data to a browser. Could you elaborate on the end goal, so I can tailor an answer more specifically to your needs?

Comment: Sure! I need to load a list of users at a particular location for a real time presence app I'm building. Each list is large, and some lists contain small base64-encoded images, further growing the file size. I need to show the user the list of users as quickly as possible, so a stream-based approach would be ideal here. Waiting 10-20 secs for the full dataset to load is not feasible for usability reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to optimize your download time from 10-20secs to a few milliseconds by starting with some [denormalization](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html).

For example, we could move the images and any other peripherals comprising the majority of the payload to their own path, keep only the meta data (name, email, etc) in the user records, and grab the extras separately:

```
/users/user_id/name, email, etc...
/images/user_id/...
```

The number of event listeners you attach or paths you connect to does not have any significant overhead locally or for networking bandwidth (just the payload) so you can do something like this to "normalize" after grabbing the meta data:

```
var firebaseRef = new Firebase(URL);
firebaseRef.child('users').on('child_added', function(snap) {
   console.log('got user ', snap.name());

   // I chose once() here to snag the image, assuming they don't change much
   // but on() would work just as well
   firebaseRef.child('images/'+snap.name()).once('value', function(imageSnap) {
       console.log('got image for user ', imageSnap.name());
   });
});
```

You'll notice right away that when you move the bulk of the data out and keep only the meta info for users locally, they will be lightning-fast to grab (all of the "got user" logs will appear right away). Then the images will trickle in one at a time after this, allowing you to create progress bars or process them as they show up.

If you aren't willing to denormalize the data, there are a couple ways you could break up the loading process. Here's a simple [pagination approach](https://gist.github.com/katowulf/2faa63affadc9e89ea77) to grab the users in segments:

```
var firebaseRef = new Firebase(URL);
grabNextTen(firebaseRef, null);

function grabNextTen(ref, startAt) {
   ref.limit(startAt? 11 : 10).startAt(startAt).once('value', function(snap) {
      var lastEntry;
      snap.forEach(function(userSnap) {
         // skip the startAt() entry, which we've already processed
         if( userSnap.name() === lastEntry ) { return; }
         processUser(userSnap);
         lastEntry = userSnap.name();
      });

      // setTimeout closes the call stack, allowing us to recurse
      // infinitely without a maximum call stack error
      setTimeout(grabNextTen.bind(null, ref, lastEntry);
   });
}

function processUser(snap) {
   console.log('got user', snap.name());
}

function didTenUsers(lastEntry) {
   console.log('finished up to ', lastEntry);
}
```

A third popular approach would be to store the images in a static cloud asset like Amazon S3 and simply store the URLs in Firebase. For large data sets in the hundreds of thousands this is very economical, since those solutions are a bit cheaper than Firebase storage.

But I'd highly suggest you both read the article on denormalization and invest in that approach first.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! The pagination approach looks like what I need - I'll try it out and report back. Most of the per-user payload is metadata, which it would be awkward to denormalize. Payloads containing b64 images are really an edge case for me, as they don't appear very often.